# UIPickerview without displaying "the wheel"

Tags: swift, uipickerview

So, I'm sorry for asking this, because I suspect my limited programming vocabulary is the reason I can't find the answer by searching. So:

I want to implement a UIPickerview-like thing, but I don't want it to display the alternatives above and below the selected value, just the selected value. It will be filled with strings: numbers 0-24 and "Off". I need to be able to get the currently selected value. UIPickerview fulfill, so far I know, everything but my need to make it smaller and more minimalistic.

I've read some threads about making the picker smaller, but my main concern is to remove the stuff above and below the selected value (and since I don't know what to call those things, my Googleing failed).

[image]

So I want "Mo...", "Sun...", "San.." and "San..." gone. I've made the picker very thin on purpose, since it only need to fit a maximum of 3 characters.

I want something like this:

```
^    ^
9    2
v    v

Those are two different pickers.
```

Comment: You could always post the image to dropbox and then put in the url.

Comment: You cannot change the height of a picker. You can try _covering_ the upper and lower parts with opaque views. But why do you want this? It's going to be unfamiliar and hard to use.

Comment: The program is a specific purpose calculator, and there are a total of eight values like this to be set, and I want to fit them all in to one view, to speed up the setting of values.

I'm thinking something like this: 

^
9
v

Oops, don't know how to do line breaks, see updated question.

Comment: did you follow any tutorial before asking?

Comment: I don't know what to ask for, and that is the problem. If you know a decent tutorial, I'd be happy to watch it and close this question.

Comment: I suspect you'd have much better luck creating your own custom view with a label and two buttons as subviews.